# Swatting an insect and the meaning behind it

Tags: verbs

I need to know whether when someone swats an insect like a fly, it would allude that the person has already killed it or it is considered as only an attempt to kill the insect which based on the context/speech content can either indicate the insect has been killed or it has flown away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to swat a fly can mean to hit it and kill it or it can mean to hit and it gets away.

I spent my afternoon swatting flies in the office after the storm. [somewhat ambiguous because you can't tell if they were all killed or not, really]

Mostly, you swat flies to try and kill them, but sometimes they get away.

**Swatting is not always synonymous with killing a fly. Sometimes it is.**

"What are all these dead flies on the desk?"
Answer: The ones I swatted.

This is the answer to your actual question.

Comment: Many thanks @Lambie . So, as far as I understood, the connotation depends on the content of conversation or context; right? :)

Comment: @A-friend Right. I really cannot stand buzzing flies and sometimes when they have managed to get into the house and start buzzing around, I get paranoid and think they know I'm coming for them. My motto for flies is: swat to kill.

Comment: Good job @Lambie; it was so funny; however, we're on the same wavelength. :))

Answer (score 2):

If I wanted to emphasize the fact that I did not actually kill the fly, I might add the preposition *at*. I think

> “I swatted the fly.”

implies a hit, whereas

> “I swatted at the fly.”

might imply a less successful result.

Perhaps worth noting: most dictionary definitions seem to indicate that *swat* implies a hit – but not always. In fact, American Heritage lists two meanings:

> **swat** (*verb*) To strike or hit with a sharp blow.
>   **swat** (*verb*) To strike or try to strike something with a sharp blow.

If you wanted to emphasize that you in fact did not harm any flies, a better verb to use might be *shoo*; from NOAD:

> **shoo** (*verb*) make (a person or animal) go away by waving one's arms at them

So:

> I shooed the fly away.

could indicate that you might have moved your hand in a swatting motion, but the fly flew away.