# What verb, phrase or phrasal verb do you use when you are waving your hand to scare off or kill a fly?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

What verb, phrase or phrasal verb do you use when you are waving your hand to scare off or kill a fly? Can I say *swat at*? For example:

> I **swatted at** a fly for hours with no success.

I am sure there are others phrases, but I can't remember it. It sounds like *spat away* or *bat away*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Swatted at* is fine here, to mean that trying to hit the fly. There’s even a device called a [fly swatter](https://www.amazon.com/Fly-Swatters/b?ie=UTF8&node=13638746011) for this purpose. See also [Swatting an insect and the meaning behind it](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/206561).

Another option is *[shoo](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shoo)*, but this has the connotation that you’re just waving your hand at the fly and not trying to kill it.

See this quote from [Science Daily](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2015/05/150514132907.htm):

> A fruit fly starts buzzing around food at a picnic, so you wave your hand over the insect and shoo it away.

Comment: Yes, there is a different between "to swat" and "to swat at". If you swat something then the implication is that you made contact. If you swat at something then you tried but missed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comment! I would like to know the word or phrase for physical action. It's on the tip of my tongue. Is it "spat away" or "bat away"?

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope “Bat away” means to try to hit too: imagine a baseball bat. “Spat away” isn’t a phrasal verb that’s idiomatic but presumably that would involve spitting   :p